# CouchDB - ODBC - Possible?

Tags: odbc, couchdb

I've been setting up a couchdb stack to support combining very versatile data sources. The output is a javascript Map Reduce library that is reusable.

With just 4 lines of config (a filter on document types, a filter on dimensions, a filter on dates and a filter on metrics) users can merge for example Omniture and DoubleClick data across a common set of dimensions, the output view is: a key consisting of a datestamp and various dimensions and a value that is a dictionary of metric names and the sum of their values.

Now I have to visualize this data in a tool that can only connect to ODBC, so find myself setting up a relational server for all these views. I am aware that MongoDB can use: http://www.simba.com/connectors/mongodb-odbc is there anything like this around for CouchDB?

If not, what are the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but I don't think it makes sense. As far as I know, ODBC doesn't match very well to CouchDB's map/reduce query interface. If no one has done it, it's likely because other people also thought it didn't make much sense.